# why is this code not putting out the questions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

```py
import random

def get_questions():
    questionBank = []
    questionBank.append(["how many steps are in the eiffel tower?", "1770", "10838"])
    questionBank.append(["how many different flavours of gummy bears are there?", "4", "5"])
    questionBank.append(["how many pizzas are eaten in the US per year?", "3 billion", "1,5 million"])

    return questionBank


def play_quiz():
    questions = get_questions()

    random.shuffle(questions)

    s: List[str]
    for s in questions:
        print(s[0] + "is it" + s[1] + "or" + s[2])
```

When I run this it simply does not print anything. Can someone help me understand why

Comment: Did you call `play_quiz()` ?

Comment: Why does `a = 6` not print anything?! Why does `play_quiz = lambda: print('yo')` not print anything?? You defined some objects (the two functions), but never used them (never called them). Why are you expecting _any_ kind of action to happen?

Answer (score 3):

Let's review what you have in your code example:

- the `random` module is being imported
- the `get_questions` function is being defined
- the `play_quiz` function is being defined

That's it. Apart from function definitions, your code is not actually doing anything. If you want to execute a function, you have to call it, e.g. `play_quiz()` as Somraj suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give a call to the `play_quiz()` function in the end.

```
import random

def get_questions():
    questionBank = []
    questionBank.append(["how many steps are in the eiffel tower?", "1770", "10838"])
    questionBank.append(["how many different flavours of gummy bears are there?", "4", "5"])
    questionBank.append(["how many pizzas are eaten in the US per year?", "3 billion", "1,5 million"])

    return questionBank


def play_quiz():
    questions = get_questions()

    # print a random question
    question = random.choice(questions)
    if question:
        print(question[0] + " is it " + question[1] + " or " + question[2])

play_quiz()
```

If you have an option of `int` type in your question, you can convert it to a string using the `str(question[option_index])`

Comment: thank you, now it worked, the only problem now is that it is printing all of the three questions, when i would like only one to be presented at a time. Do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: @edwardthecoder So why exactly are you iterating through the questions when you don't want to iterate them but just to pick one of them?

Comment: i am sorry, i am new to python but i dont know what i am doing wrong here, would you like to help me making only one question appear at a time

Comment: yes i just saw it, thank you. When i have deleted every question from the list. With which command do i reset the list?

Comment: Try to make a new dictionary instead of the old one and then you can reference back to the old dictionary. You can click the gray checkmark if you like my answer.

Comment: Hey @edwardthecoder, I edited the code that will now print a random question from the list of questions.

Comment: somray chowdhury where can i see the edited code that you did?

Comment: The answer above the comments, you can see my name under the post

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `play_quiz():`  function.
Try adding this to your code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    play_quiz()
```

Or just simply add a line calling the `play_quiz()` method by adding:

```
play_quiz()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `play_quiz()` and you are asking all of the questions in the `for` loop. Pick a random question out of the quiz and then let the person answer it. Then make a new list without the just-asked question. Repeat until there are no questions left to answer. This way you can reset.